# FreeDOS edit command failing

Tags: windows-98

I am installing Windows 98 on to a computer which lacks an OS. I am using FreeDOS to do so. However, I need to edit the "config.sys" file in order to load the required files, and for whatever reason, the "edit" command fails, stating that it is not a command. Also, I can not find the config file in Windows Explorer, so I can not modify them with my working computer.

Comment: You can't find the `config.sys` file using Windows Explorer because it has the Hidden/System attributes set. You need to turn on the option to show both hidden and system files in order to see it.

Comment: I already had this option enabled.

Comment: You might want to run `dir *.sys /a` or `attrib *.sys` from a command prompt to ensure the file is there.

Comment: I can find it on the old computer, just not my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting "Bad command or filename" or similar when trying to run `EDIT` because EDIT.COM or EDIT.EXE is not in the current directory or anywhere in the path.  Issue a plain `PATH` command to see what directories are in the current path to confirm.  You may need to look around the directories on the FreeDOS floppy and see where it is, if it's included.

Failing that, you can do the following, though it will be inconvenient:

- Enter `TYPE CONFIG.SYS` from the place CONFIG.SYS is in.  This will display the current contents of CONFIG.SYS.
- Now enter `COPY CON CONFIG.TMP`.  The cursor will jump to the next line and you'll get no prompt.
- What you type will be entered into the `CONFIG.TMP` file.  You can then `COPY CONFIG.TMP CONFIG.SYS` once you make `CONFIG.TMP` the way you need it.  You'll need to type out everything from start to finish that should be in the final CONFIG.SYS file, with any changes or additions you want to make made as you type.
- When done, press ENTER to get a blank line, then CTRL-Z.  You'll get a message the file is copied.  Verify the changes are there with a second `TYPE CONFIG.SYS` command.
- The `COPY CON CONFIG.TMP` will replace `CONFIG.TMP` with everything you type, so `COPY CONFIG.SYS CONFIG.TMP` won't help you.

Hopefully your CONFIG.SYS fits on one screen if you have to go this route.

Comment: Can't go the second route, the disk is not rewritable.

Comment: Do you know where I could pick up a copy of edit.exe?

Comment: @CaffeineToCode For example [here](http://www.freedos.org/software/?prog=edit).